# Sequentially replace multiple places matching single pattern in a string with different replacements

Tags: regex, r, stringr, stringi

Using `stringr` package, it is easy to perform regex replacement in a vectorized manner.

**Question: How can I do the following:**

Replace every word in

```
hello,world??your,make|[]world,hello,pos
```

to different replacements, e.g. increasing numbers

```
1,2??3,4|[]5,6,7
```

Note that simple separators cannot be assumed, the practical use case is more complicated.

---

`stringr::str_replace_all` does not seem to work because it

```
str_replace_all(x, "(\\w+)", 1:7)
```

produces a vector for each replacement applied to all words, or it has 
uncertain and/or duplicate input entries so that

```
str_replace_all(x, c("hello" = "1", "world" = "2", ...))
```

will not work for the purpose.

Comment: You can use the `gsubfn` package for this.

Answer (score 8):

Here's another idea using `gsubfn`.  The `pre` function is run before the substitutions and the `fun` function is run for each substitution:

```
library(gsubfn)
x <- "hello,world??your,make|[]world,hello,pos"
p <- proto(pre = function(t) t$v <- 0, # replace all matches by 0 
           fun = function(t, x) t$v <- v + 1) # increment 1 
gsubfn("\\w+", p, x)
```

Which gives:

```
[1] "1,2??3,4|[]5,6,7"
```

This variation would give the same answer since gsubfn maintains a `count` variable for use in proto functions:

```
pp <- proto(fun = function(...) count)
gsubfn("\\w+", pp, x)
```

See the gsubfn vignette for examples of using `count`.

Comment: Very nice answer.  Glad to see you using other functions besides `dplyr` these days ;)

Comment: could you explain the function used in the replacement part?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest the ["ore" package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ore/index.html) for something like this. Of particular note would be `ore.search` and `ore.subst`, the latter of which can accept a function as the replacement value.

Examples:

```
library(ore)

x <- "hello,world??your,make|[]world,hello,pos"

## Match all and replace with the sequence in which they are found
ore.subst("(\\w+)", function(i) seq_along(i), x, all = TRUE)
# [1] "1,2??3,4|[]5,6,7"

## Create a cool ore object with details about what was extracted
ore.search("(\\w+)", x, all = TRUE)
#   match: hello world  your make   world hello pos
# context:      ,     ??    ,    |[]     ,     ,   
#  number: 1==== 2====  3=== 4===   5==== 6==== 7==
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a base R solution. It should also be vectorized.

```
x="hello,world??your,make|[]world,hello,pos"
#split x into single chars
x_split=strsplit(x,"")[[1]]
#find all char positions and replace them with "a"
x_split[gregexpr("\\w", x)[[1]]]="a"
#find all runs of "a"
rle_res=rle(x_split)
#replace run lengths by 1
rle_res$lengths[rle_res$values=="a"]=1
#replace run values by increasing number
rle_res$values[rle_res$values=="a"]=1:sum(rle_res$values=="a")
#use inverse.rle on the modified rle object and collapse string
paste0(inverse.rle(rle_res),collapse="")

#[1] "1,2??3,4|[]5,6,7"
```